# Can't send Webhook request from Actions

Tags: actions-on-google

Im having problems contacting my web hook, I tried changing from Inline Script (is down below) to WebHook to my server api and with a direct json file on a web server that doesn't require authentication, but Im not having success, this is the script that I use to call my server:

```
https.get({
    host: 'myurl.eu.ngrok.io',
    path: 'apipath/function-called',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'mytoken',
    },
}, function(response) {
    let json = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('received JSON response: ' + chunk);
        json += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        let jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
        let stockPrice = jsonData.data[0].value;

        console.log('the stock price received is:' + stockPrice);

        let chat = 'The' + priceType + ' price for ' + companyName +
            ' on ' + date + ' was ' + stockPrice;

        CloudFnResponse.send(buildChatResponse(chat));
    });
});
```

when I test the Intent on Dialogflow they return me a 403, because the API requires authentication, when I try to do the same thing from Actions and with a logged account with Oauth / Google Sign In the error is this:

```
"responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 14,
      "message": "Webhook error (206)"
    }
```

but watching the logs, I don't receive the request, giving a look to the exception from Cloud Platform, the server that answers doesn't have the headers my server use, I don't use NGNIX

```
Received response from agent with body: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.13.6 Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 08:15:48 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 534 X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 6441a38beda637638dfd2e6b1f3e9c8a/7766163845645599757;o=0 Google-Actions-API-Version: 2 Via: 1.1 google Alt-Svc: clear 

{
  "conversationToken": "[]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "text request"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "speechBiasingHints": [
        "$measureUnit",
        "$product"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 14,
      "message": "Webhook error (206)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "d060e25c-2e4e-4c7e-903b-5cb55c13a6f0",
      "parameterNames": [
        "product",
        "quantity",
        "measureUnit"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

anyone knows what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem seemed to be the 2nd version of the agent, the Web hook error is supossed to return the [Error Code](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works#handle_errors) of the page, but it didnt.